# Why two TCP connections to mysql server?

Tags: mysql, port, tcp, netstat

When I connect to a mysql server via a client, it seems to create two new TCP connections each time, for example doing:

```
$ netstat -a |grep mysql
# tcp4       0      0  lmy.att.64710 ec2-54-00.mysql ESTABLISHED
# tcp4       0      0  lmy.att.64705 ec2-54-00.mysql ESTABLISHED
```

What does it need the two TCP connections for, and why wouldn't it just create a single one?

Comment: You didn't specify what the client is, so all anyone can give you is wild guesses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried using MySQL workbench and Sequel Pro and they both opened two.

Comment: What version of mysql?